# How to check if id existed in another table before we trigger insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

**my_Image** table description

```
name    characterVarying(30),
image    oid,
mime_type charactervarying(30)
```

**pg_largeobject** table description

```
loid oid
```

My Query:

```
insert into myImage values('myImage', lo_from_bytea(999999,decode('RRRXFFDF','base64')),'jpg');
```

Before i want to trigger my query in postgres. I want to make sure that in table `pg_largeObject` this value 999999 wont be present in postgres. so can you please help me in writing my insert statement. if not exists that loid then only my insert statement should trigger. please help me in writing insert statement or stored procedure here.

Comment: you can use `insert..select... where not exists(select where 99999)` but it wont be atomic - if you need it stable for high concurrency, use UPSERT or write a plpgsql with excception handling...

Comment: can you give me full query. I am new in writing queries. if possible. i can use this (select where 99999) because this 99999  is the one we are supplying here manually. With this one it creates a new row.

Comment: `insert into myImage select 'myImage', lo_from_bytea(999999,decode('RRRXFFDF','base64')),'jpg' where not exists (select 'Ravi' from myImage where image=999999 );`

Comment: i didnt understand this one in your query. (select 'Ravi' from myImage where image=999999 ); why Ravi came here?Please provide me working query.

Comment: put anything instead. People keep asking why they should `select null` in `where exists` - so I'm explicitly using ANYTHING - not null

Comment: insert into myImage select 'myImage', lo_from_bytea(999999,decode('RRRXFFDF','base64')),'jpg' where not exists (select * from pg_largeObject where loid=999999 );This query worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into myImage select 'myImage', lo_from_bytea(999999,decode('RRRXFFDF','base64')),'jpg' 
where not exists (
  select null from pg_largeObject where loid=999999
);
```

mind that in `select null` part `NULL` is insignificant - ther can be any value returned if row exists.

Also mind this solution could fail on highly concurrent systems, as subquery is not atomic

Answer (score 0):

Vao Tsun answer with slight modifcation on select statement:

insert into myImage select 'myImage', lo_from_bytea(999999,decode('RRRXFFDF','base64')),'jpg' where not exists (select * from pg_largeObject where loid=999999 );

Comment: I modified query to meet your need and also provided additional info in my answer, please accept instead of answering yourself